# Print all PID from a tasklist command result

Tags: windows, tasklist, taskkill

I am trying to display all the PID from several processes printed as a result from the tasklist command.
Can somebody help me please ?

I also have another issue.When I run the `tasklist /FI "Imagename eq javaw.exe" /FI "Windowtitle ne Jenkins*"` the result is ok.
But when I run `taskkill /F /IM javaw.exe "Windowtitle ne Jenkins*"` no task is found,but it exist. 
I also checked `taskkill /F /FI "Imagename eq javaw.exe" "Windowtitle ne Jenkins*"`

Any ideea why this strage behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself.

The code bellow print all processes PID from an application (in my case : `javaw.exe`)

`for /f "tokens=1,2 delims = " %%A in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq javaw.exe" ^| find ^"javaw^"') do echo %%B`

My seconds question still has no answer yet.